# Android Service Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, service, automated-tests

How to test my `IBinder` object that `Service` return on `onBind` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's according to the remote interface that you use between your context and the service (in remote call scenario).
For example you can do like this:

```
IBinder service = this.bindService(new Intent(TestService.class.getName()));
assertNotNull(service);
assertTrue(service instanceof ITestServiceCall); //see if the service returns the correct interface
ITestServiceCall iTestServiceCall = ITestServiceCall.Stub.asInterface(service);
assertNotNull(iTestServiceCall);
iTestServiceCall.doSomething();
```

The ITestServiceCall is the interface that you define in an AIDL file (**ITestServiceCall.aidl**).

But before this can work you have to make sure your service returns the Stub of your interface correctly on **onBind()**.

I hope this can help.

Comment: it's a bad idea to test your binder right after having called bindService. This method is asynchronous and returns nothing interesting before your ServiceConnection's onServiceConnected is called

Comment: There is no `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` used in ServiceTestCase, that's why we get the IBinder object immediately after the `bindService()`. This is different from the actual service flow I think.